# Nearby or within search for clauses

Tags: mongodb, solr

I have divided multiple sentences into clauses(like A,B,C.....Z).

Now I want to **search** **computer** and **mouse** in these clauses such that they lie **within a range of 3 clauses**. I know that this can be done using languages, but that would be slow and mine is not a one time process. I want to use it in a search engine so I am trying to find out if there is any existing database that has this as inbuilt functionality or something closer to this.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've tagged this with Solr, the regular Lucene syntax for this would be:

```
"computer mouse"~2
```

(this means that there can be two tokens between each term).

If you're using the dismax or edismax query syntax in Solr, you can use the phrase slop setting (`ps`) to say the same thing.

Comment: I do not want to use the simple proximity search.

I want the results returned if the two words lie in adjacent clauses. The words themselves may or may not be next to each other.

For example : 
A computer is an electrical device that has a mouse as an input device.
Lets say that this sentence is divided into two clauses
a: A computer is an electrical device
b: that has a mouse as an input device

I want this returned if I search for computer and mouse since the two words lie in adjacent clauses.

Comment: You could probably get around it by using the clause index as the position of each term generated (which would be similar to what a synonym filter does). How would you parse the sentence into clauses?

Comment: When I started I wanted to test out if this could be done on the fly(during query execution), but I guess when the dataset will be very big the process will be highly resource intensive.
Then I also considered the possibility of splitting the sentences on certain break words or maybe generating clauses using npl and saving in the database as is.

Comment: You'll want to preprocess something like this - and you'll have to have proper rules for what is a clause in a sentence. Look into NLP libraries for your language of choice.

Comment: Yes, I am also considering preprocessing it using NLP, but the tricky part according to me will be using proximity search inside the clauses. Do you have any idea how can it be done?

Comment: I described an idea in the previous answer; (Lucene terminology) index the position of each term inside the clause as the clause index, meaning that all terms in the clause take up the same position logically. Proximities would then work according to which clause the terms were attached to instead of their individual sequence in the text.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, will provide an update when I try it out.